# Trouble with CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am learning CTE, and tried out the following query

```
WITH fooCTE
AS 
(
SELECT TOP 5 f.bar FROM foobar f
)
```

But it's displaying an error which is quite incomprehensible.

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Infact when I run the query below, I get the top five values being displayed.

```
SELECT TOP 5 f.bar FROM foobar f
96.8
92.4
99.3
68.9
74.8

SELECT f.bar from foobar f;
96.8
92.4
99.3
68.9
74.8
69.3
94.6
74.8
36.4
92.6
69.4
99.2
39.9
96.2
99.1
```

I hope am not wrong with the syntax and stuff. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined fooCTE but you do nothing with it.
try:

```
WITH fooCTE
AS 
(
SELECT TOP 5 f.bar FROM foobar f
)
select * from fooCTE
```

Comment: Thank you :) and I have another doubt the CTE is only valid for that session right?

Comment: the CTE is valid for the current statement only.

Comment: @OvidiuPacurar No, you can use it any statement.  Here is a an example of an UPDATE statement with a CTE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ee784/3 in answer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722528/update-between-two-tables-when-there-is-no-relation-between-them/16886155#16886155