# Update between two tables when there is no relation between them

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need a SQL statement which fills the null values from the second column of #T1 table with values from #T2(C1).

There is no foreign key or match between the columns of those two tables.

Sample:

```
T1 (C1, T2C1)
A1, 1
A2, null
A3, null
A4, 4
A5, null
-------------
T2 (C1)
a
b
```

After update, the T1 will look like:

```
A1, 1
A2, a
A3, b
A4, 4
A5, null
```

I found two approaches:

Using CTE

```
create table #T1 (C1 varchar(10), T2C1 varchar(10))
create table #T2 (C1 varchar(10))

insert into #T1 values ('A1', '1')
insert into #T1 values ('A2', null)
insert into #T1 values ('A3', null)
insert into #T1 values ('A4', '4')
insert into #T1 values ('A5', null)

insert into #T2 values ('a')
insert into #T2 values ('b')

;with t2 as
(
select C1, row_number() over (order by C1) as Index2
from #T2
)
,t1 as
(
select T2C1, row_number() over (order by C1) as Index1   
from #T1
where T2C1 is null
)
update t1
set t1.T2C1 = t2.C1
from t2
where t1.Index1 = t2.Index2

select * from #T1

drop table #T1
drop table #T2
```

With Derived Tables

```
create table #T1 (C1 varchar(10), T2C1 varchar(10))
create table #T2 (C1 varchar(10))

insert into #T1 values ('A1', '1')
insert into #T1 values ('A2', null)
insert into #T1 values ('A3', null)
insert into #T1 values ('A4', '4')
insert into #T1 values ('A5', null)

insert into #T2 values ('a')
insert into #T2 values ('b')

update #T1
set T2C1 = cj.C1
from #T1
join (select T2C1, row_number() over (order by C1) as Index1, C1
   from #T1
   where T2C1 is null) ci on ci.C1 = #T1.C1
join (select C1, row_number() over (order by C1) as Index2
  from #T2) cj on ci.Index1 = cj.Index2

select * from #T1

drop table #T1
drop table #T2
```

My question is, can I achieve this without using windowing functions and with no cursors?

**Update**

@Damien_The_Unbeliever correctly points that to do this kind of update it is not possible without defining an ordering on tables, actually I think exactly said is without properly identify and link the rows from target table.

@Bogdan Sahlean has found another way, using table variables and IDENTITY column, which I'm happy with this solution, it's another way
However, in the real application I will still use the windowing functions

Thanks all

Comment: There is no inherent ordering to tables, and you're trying to impose one. I don't see how you'd do it without a window function or cursor.

Comment: I'm living with the fact maybe I'm missing something, I know that the only join between those tables will be a cartesian product, N x M where M > 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.I suppose you have a `pk` in target table (#T1).

2.Instead of ROW_NUMBER this solution uses `IDENTITY(1,1)` columns and two table variables.

3.I didn't tested this solution.

```
DECLARE @t2_count INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #T2);

DECLARE @Target TABLE
(
     MyId INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,T1_pk INT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
INSERT  @Target (T1_pk)
SELECT  TOP(@t2_count) pk
FROM    #T1 
WHERE   T2C1 IS NULL;

DECLARE @Source TABLE
(
     MyId INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,C1 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);
INSERT  @Source (C1)
SELECT  C1
FROM    #T2;

UPDATE  #T1
SET     T2C1 = src.C1
FROM    #T1 t
INNER JOIN @Target trg ON t.pk = trg.T1_pk 
INNER JOIN @Source src ON trg.MyId = src.MyId;
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Damien, anyway when you will rely on the engine and make a premise that the table is ordered by the C1 column (which depends only on the DB and you can not rely on that  ) the you could issue an update statement which will update all the rows

```
declare @a int
set @a = 0

update #t1
set t2c1 = @a,
@a = @a+1
```

But I wouldn't do that.

Comment: It doesn't really matter the order. In the real application, the scenario is this: I have a list of barcodes in a CSV file, which I put it in table, using bulk insert. Then for each product stock, that hasn't already a barcode (here the null condition) I assign a barcode. The order in which the barcodes are assigned it doesn't matter, the only condition is to keep the list unique.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [CTE](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/) along with [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.110%29.aspx):

```
WITH cte_t1 AS
(
  SELECT
   T2C1
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY C1) AS id
  FROM T1
  WHERE T2C1 IS NULL
)
,cte_t2 AS
(
  SELECT 
   C1
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY C1) AS id
  FROM T2
)
UPDATE t1
  SET t1.T2C1 = t2.C1
  FROM cte_t1 AS t1
  INNER JOIN cte_t2 AS t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
;
```

The ROW_NUMBER creates an identifier based on the order the columns are in (which I am assuming is what you are looking for, but note that SQL does not have an order instead this query is relying on the physical order of the records which is not a good idea but it looks like that is what you are dealing with).  We then join on this identifier and update the records in T1 with the values in T2.

I have placed this solution on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ee784/3).

If you can look into create new tables with some type of identifier that links them together, then you would not have to rely on the physical order of the records.

Comment: Please check the comment posted by Damian. I don't have a specific order on the tables. The order is as how they physically are in the table.